# Bootstrap calendar doesn't gave the same value

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

In my code I am trying to check if the age of the user is above 18 years.
For my input field I am using the bootstrap date input. The code works perfectly when I type the date, but when I use the datepicker to choose a date it always returns true.

Here is my function:

```
$date = $_POST['birthdate'];
$orderdate = explode('-', $date);
$byr = $orderdate[0];
$bmon = $orderdate[1];
$bday = $orderdate[2];

function check21 ($bday, $bmon, $byr) {
    if (date('Y') - $byr > 18) { return true; } else {
        if (date('Y') - $byr = 18) { 
            if (date('m') - $bmon > 0) { return true; } else {
                if (date('m') - $bmon = 0) {
                    if (date('d') - $bday >= 0) { return true; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (check21($bday, $bmon, $byr)) { 
    echo 'user is above 18';

} else { 
    echo 'user is not 18 years old'; 
}
```

And here is my date input field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" name="birthdate" class="form-control input-mini login-input" required>
</div>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Verify what format the bootstrap picker is sending the date as. There are also smarter ways of doing this with the DateTime class.

Comment: What do you mean by `always returns true`?

Comment: what is the result of `var_dump($_POST['birthdate']);` ?

Comment: When I do that I get the same output as when I type it manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using [this plugin](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#configuration), try setting the date format on javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

And on the server you can improve your code like this:

```
<?php

$date = $_POST['birthdate'] ?? null; // do some validation if you want
$birthdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date); // create a datetime instance, result will be false if $date has the wrong format

function check21($birthdate) {
    // check if the today date minus 18 years is prior to the birth date
    return $birthdate <= (new DateTime())->modify('-18 years');
}

if (check21($birthdate)) { 
    echo 'user is above 18';
} else { 
    echo 'user is not 18 years old'; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tell the format is right! When I echo it the format is already on yyyy-mm-dd